# What ports do I need to open on my UFW firewall? I cannot log into nyx. Do I need to also open my 9051/tcp port?

Tags: configuration, relays, nyx, firewall

I have just installed tor middle relay using [this youtube](https://youtu.be/npg3cBJusnA) guide.
I did everything up until the [12th minute](https://youtu.be/npg3cBJusnA?t=717) of this video.
I have tor installed on a vps server I run from Vultr.
Then I have installed this tor monitor tool called `nyx`.

My intention is to run a middle relay with it, to help tor network.
I think everything is working fine but I don't know, which ports should I open on my UFW firewall?
I've opened 9001, because I feel it's obvious it needs to be allowed.

This is my current UWF setup:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
[sudo] password for <my_login>:
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     DENY IN     Anywhere
27119/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
19302/tcp                  DENY IN     Anywhere
9001/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
19302/tcp (v6)             DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
9001/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I cannot log into `nyx`, and I feel I did everything as shown in the YouTube video.
But when I try 2 log into `nyx` and when I paste password using right mouse click (I'm using PowerShell to log into my vps) I get "incorrect password" output.

```
<my_login>@debian:~$ nyx
Tor controller password:
Incorrect password
```

I got the password from this site:
https://www.lastpass.com/features/password-generator#generatorTool
then I hashed it, the same way, that is shown on the video.

It's my first attempt to configuring tor middle relay.
I could use some help.
Should I also allow in my 9051/tcp port?? The default Control Port.

```
## The port on which Tor will listen for local connections from Tor
## controller applications, as documented in control-spec.txt.
ControlPort 9051
## If you enable the controlport, be sure to enable one of these
## authentication methods, to prevent attackers from accessing it.
HashedControlPassword 16:my_password's_hash
#CookieAuthentication 1
```

What is the difference between `tor.service` and `tor@default.service`?

```
<my_login>@debian:~$ sudo systemctl status tor
[sudo] password for <my_login>:
● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2023-02-06 23:33:50 UTC; 1h 3min ago
    Process: 757 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 757 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 715us

Feb 06 23:33:50 debian systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Feb 06 23:33:50 debian systemd[1]: Finished Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

Comment: Hi, I would suggest not using anything from YouTube. Instead, here is the guide from torproject.org.  The Tor Project runs the Tor network, assume that they are the experts, not random people from YouTube. https://community.torproject.org/relay/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open any ports for nyx: it's using localhost. To specify it better add **ControlListenAddress 127.0.0.1:9051** to your torrc and it will be just fine. Service names you're asking for is a bit weirdo related to the Linux *systemd* - this setup allows you to have multiple tor instances running on your system - it's useful for multi-homed setups and for running a hidden services on the same physical host as well